# OSX postgres 9.1.4 timestamp with time zone order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

At OSX 10.8 on postresql server 9.1.4 is a unexpected behavior.
Since on Ubuntu 12.04 it was correct.

To reproduce this issue use the the following postgres sql example database.
Note: 
The timestamp values are selected in time zone 'Europe/Berlin' and the timestamps are around the DST end in [2012](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=37) which was the case of this test.

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE data;
CREATE TABLE data (
"id" int8 NOT NULL,
"timestampwithtimezone" timestamp(6) WITH TIME ZONE,
CONSTRAINT "data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
COMMIT;

BEGIN; 
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (205,'2012-10-28 01:30:00+02');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (204,'2012-10-28 02:00:00+02');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (203,'2012-10-28 02:30:00+02');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (202,'2012-10-28 02:59:59+02');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (106,'2012-10-28 02:00:00+01');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (107,'2012-10-28 02:30:00+01');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (108,'2012-10-28 02:59:59+01');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (109,'2012-10-28 03:00:00+01');
INSERT INTO data (id, timestampwithtimezone) VALUES (110,'2012-10-28 03:30:00+01');
COMMIT;
```

---

If I type the following SQL query which only looks for the last existent timestamp before a given timestamp:

```
SELECT id, timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as timestampwithtimezone
FROM data
WHERE 
timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' 
< cast('2012-10-28T02:30:00.000+01' AS timestamp)
ORDER BY timestampwithtimezone DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

my expected result was:

║ 106 ║ 2012-10-28 02:00:00 ║

Since I want the last timestamp before a given (2012-10-28T02:30:00.000+01) timestamp.
But the result contains:

║ 204 ║ 2012-10-28 02:00:00 ║

It seems that postgresqls sorting is wrong in this case. Under Ubuntu I get the right answer which was id: 106 and NOT 204.

BUT:

If I set up this query: (Only difference is that I dropped the result set mapping to the time zone):

```
SELECT id, timestampwithtimezone
FROM data
WHERE timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' 
< cast('2012-10-28T02:30:00.000+01' AS timestamp)
ORDER BY timestampwithtimezone DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

The result set in OSX 10.8 is as expected as well as in Ubuntu 12.04:

║ 106 ║ 2012-10-28 02:00:00+01 ║

Why is there a difference between the OS versions?
And the answer '204' to this query in this case is really wrong.
But why there is a difference in the result set if I map the timestamp to a time zone? To my knowledge postgresql uses internally UTC to store timestamps. So the DST should be not a problem in the timeline.
Why this happens?

Thanks in advance in the hope of a response.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer was wrong.

Based on you data. Both answers are good.

In 2012-10-28 there was time change from Summer time to winter time ([Here it is explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30787/at-time-zone-with-zone-name-postgresql-bug)).

Look at hours in this result:

```
select id, 
  timestampwithtimezone, 
  timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as berlin  
from data 
order by berlin ;


 id  | timestampwithtimezone  |       berlin        
-----+------------------------+---------------------
 205 | 2012-10-28 01:30:00+02 | 2012-10-28 01:30:00
 204 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00+02 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00
 106 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00+01 | 2012-10-28 02:00:00
 203 | 2012-10-28 02:30:00+02 | 2012-10-28 02:30:00
 202 | 2012-10-28 02:59:59+02 | 2012-10-28 02:59:59
```

Records with id 204 and 106 have the same value in berlin column.

Read question and answers from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30787/at-time-zone-with-zone-name-postgresql-bug).

If you want to order by timestamptz do not use alias for column as the same name

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as timestampwithtimezone_alias
FROM data
WHERE 
  timestampwithtimezone at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' 
  < cast('2012-10-28T02:30:00.000' AS timestamp)
ORDER BY timestampwithtimezone DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```